# mysql LOAD DATA INFILE query problem

Tags: mysql, import

I am trying to load a dump file (csv) into mysql..
I am using the following query

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'filename.csv' INTO TABLE add_to_cart FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' (fields...);
```

But it only returns me the first row...
Why is it not going thru the complete csv file and simply giving me the first row.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the csv file has more than one line?

Then, if the csv file does indeed have multiple lines, does the first row in the output table correspond to the first line of the csv file? Or does it somehow happen that the first row of the output table corresponds to the ***final*** line of the csv file?

Comment: Hi.. actually, its the first line only.. And its the correct line.. but the last field is shown as "null" instead of the present entry.. I suspect that there are some other seperators as well. other than ',' .. I think, the last entry is like ....,"blah blah blah " instead of ...,blah blah blah.. so there is this -->"<-- how do i modify my query?? thanks

Comment: Yes, look at the separators. Query looks ok, except: do yourself a big favor and, in your query, bracket the table_name and each field_name with back-ticks. If you're going to be doing MySQL a lot, this has to be a habit. Then match up the fields in the csv, the field_names in the MySQL request, and the field_names in the table structure -- what you set up when you said CREATE TABLE. If everything matches up exactly, then when you try it again it should work. See, because there's a null at the end of the output-table row, it looks like there's a mismatch somewhere among those three things.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to change it from

```
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

to

```
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to run the same command from Terminal and share the output.

If you are getting any value in skipped, as given below. Then the issue is in your table.

Query OK, 1 row affected, 65535 warnings (0.53 sec)

Records: 47355  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 4735  Warnings: 68411